# How to get the value of input field as soon as user enters it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field:

```
<input class="contact-text-filed" maxlength="50" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" type="text" value="" />
```

and js:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var subject=$("#subject").val();
        $('.test').click(function(){
            console.log(subject);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that it doesn't log the value. If I keep the value on refresh, it logs.

Comment: Is the `test` class used on a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the value on every change (including copy/paste, dragging etc) is to bind an [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) event this way:

```
$('.test').on('input', function(e) { .... });
```

It also exists in pure Javascript, you should bind it this way:

```
object.oninput = function(){ .... };
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't log the input value because you assign its value (an empty string) to `subject` var as soon as the page loads.
Assign it every time you press the button:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test').click(function(){
       var subject=$("#subject").val();
       console.log(subject);
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what exactly do you want but might be you are looking for this.

```js
$('#subject').keyup(function() {
  var subject = $(this).val();
  console.log(subject);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="contact-text-filed" maxlength="50" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" type="text" value="" class="test" />
```